# Eclipse plugin - file not found exception

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-plugin

In my plugin project, I added a new file called "database.properties", when I try to run the plugin I am getting below exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: database.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Also I have included that file in build properties, screenshot is shown here:

[image]

I tried cleaning, restarting eclipse, building etc. But still system is unable to find the file. Can anyone help me? what I am missing here?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245777-databaseproperties/

Comment: @Zenith, I forgot to mention, but if I run that class as a standalone Java app, it is able to find the file. But exception is occurring only if I try to run it as a plugin.

Comment: you could try to check what the full path is when running as a plugin

Comment: thanks, how do I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the file like that:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your_plugn_id");
InputStream is = bundle.getEntry("database.properties").openStream();
```

And includeit in your build.properties:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           OSGI-INF/,\
           database.properties/,\
           .,\
           plugin.xml
```

Comment: Thanks scawf !! References?